# Read all character including the null byte

Tags: c++, string, null, byte

I want to read out the chrome history from its file. I want to get all characters and null byte that's in that file. The problem I'm facing is that I only get some part of the text that's in the file. I belive it stop due to a null byte or a speical character.

Here´s my code that I have at the moment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string str;
    std::ifstream in("c:/Users/Petrus/Documents/History"); // I have copy my file into my documents to make sure I'm not interfering with Chrome.
    std::stringstream buffer;

    if (!in.is_open()){
        cout << "Failed to open" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Opened OK" << endl;
    }

    buffer << in.rdbuf();

    std::string contents(buffer.str());

    while (getline(buffer, str))
    {
        cout << str;
    }
    in.close();

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to take a look at the chrome history file its located at:

C:\Users\YOUR NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default -->History

(PS You have to include hidden files to be able to see Appdata.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know how it is on Windows, but on my Linux system the history database is just that, a *database*, more precisely a [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) database. So if you want to do some processing, or fetch information from it, you should probably use the right tools (i.e. [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)) to open and read it.

Answer (score 1):

`std::getline()` should be used only to read plain text files.

To read arbitrary binary files you should use `read()`. Additionally, on your operating system you must open binary files using the `std::ios::binary` flag.